# Node.js showing unclear error when using 'await' without 'async'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had an error with this code

```
exports.getResults = (req, res) => {
    status = await miDealApi.getResults()
    res.json({
        status: status
    })
}
```

The issue was that i used 'await' without declaring the method as 'async', but the error Node.js was giving me was very unclear, and didn't help me figuring it out at all.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999
    throw err;
    ^

[wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16),Module._compile
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27),Object.Module._extensions..js
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10),Module.load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32),Function.Module._load
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14),Module.require
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19),require
     (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18),Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\DT\projects\suresort-manager\controllers\waveFactory.js:6:30),Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30),Object.Module._extensions..js
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)]
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\DT\projects\suresort-manager>
```

Is there anything i can do to make errors like this clearer in the future?

Comment: The error node gives me is `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. The error chrome dev console gives me is `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. Your error is probably related to the exports module being malformed due to the async/await issue.

Comment: any function that is using `await` within needs to be `async` function

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your node.js version is a bit older, and thus, doesn't give you the proper error.

Running with Node 12 I get:

```
/project/foo.js:2
  status = await miDealApi.getResults()
           ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

So you might want to check your version?

```
node -v
12.21.0
```

You should always aim for working with at least the stable version.

Answer (score 1):

**Keep in mind:** `await` has to use with `async`.

> An **async** function is a function declared with the `async` keyword, and the `await` keyword is permitted within them. The `async` and `await` keywords enable **asynchronous**, **promise-based** behavior to be written in a cleaner style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.

Change your code like below:

```
exports.getResults = async (req, res) => {
    status = await miDealApi.getResults()
    res.json({
        status: status
    })
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: I was able to solve it, i was asking about why the error that i had was so unclear